# Can you cast the Shield spell against an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, opportunity-attack, reactions

Since  *[shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield)* is cast as a reaction, and you cannot use reactions during your turn, does that mean you cannot cast *shield* against opportunity attacks?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Reactions *can* be taken on your turn.

> A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, **which can occur on your turn** or on someone else's.

<sup>PHB, pg.190</sup>

Therefore, yes, you can cast Shield as a reaction if you provoke an opportunity attack on your turn.

Comment: Just to reinforce, a reaction needs a trigger. You usually do not have anything to trigger a reaction on your turn since you are the prime source of action during that time. The most frequent example is reacting to someone else's reaction. For instance, you could cast magic missile, your opponent could use their reaction for a shield, and you could use your reaction for a counterspell, to ensure that the original magic missile has its effect.